# Usability of <ins> and <del> elements

Tags: user-interface, diff, usability, version, revision

How usable is a document which uses `<ins>` and `<del>`, compared to seeing the deltas in a two-pane split-screen diff viewer?

Although a command-line diff tool will show its output as one diff after another (in a single vertical column / console window), all the GUI diff tools that I know of tend to show diffs in a two-pane, split-screen UI.

I'd like it if `<ins>` and `<del>` were usable but it worries me that, instead, two-pane split-screen diff viewers seem to be the norm.

Secondly, have you seen any sites or software which use the `<ins>` and `<del>` elements to show revisions, and if so would you please point them out to me? I'd like to see examples of their being used (in order to make a subjective opinion of how usable they are).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) uses this for example on its diff pages and does that even in a two-pane view. You can see an example [here](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracUbuntuMultipleProjects?action=diff&old_version=21).

Answer (score 1):

Stackoverflow shows inline diffs in the its edit history pages. So, if you're comfortable with how that works, its safe to say that its fairly usable.

The `<ins> & <del>` elements aren't used, `<span>` tags with a class are, but `<ins> & <del>` elements could have been used instead.

Comment: In this case they actually *should* use `<ins>` and `<del>` since they are semantic HTML markup elements that do exactly what they would be used for here, except they aren't used :-)